# Conditions implying that non-zero class of a circle is primitive

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, surfaces

$\newcommand{\ss}{\subset}\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}\newcommand{\cn}{\colon}\newcommand{\range}{\operatorname{range}}\newcommand{\d}{\partial}\newcommand{\ker}{\operatorname{ker}}\newcommand{\sr}[2]{\stackrel{#1}{#2}}\newcommand{\lra}{\longrightarrow}\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$

> Let $M$ be a closed orientable smooth surface and $L\ss M$ be a smooth
> $1$-submanifold diffeomorphic to the circle. Prove that the class
> $[L]\in H_1(M)$ is either zero or primitive.
>
> **Def.** An element of an abelian group $A$ is *primitive* if $a\not\in kA$ for all $k>1$.
>
> **Def.** *Closed* surface is a compact surface without boundary.
>
> **Def.** *Surface without boundary* $M$ is a Hausdorff space in which every point has an open neighbourhood homeomorphic to some open subset
> of the Euclidean plane, but there exists some $z\in M$ which is not
> homeomorphic to  any open subset of $\R^2_+=\{(x,y)\in\R^2\cn y\geq
> > 0\}$.
>
> **Def.** *Orientable surface* $M$ is a surface such that $H_1(M)$ is free abelian.
>
> **Def.** *Smooth* surface $M$ is a surface which has a tangent plane at every point.
>
> **Def.** Differentiable map is called a *diffeomorphism* if it is a bijection and its inverse is also differentiable.

I don't even know where to start here so any hints would be appreciated.

**Edit**: 1. what is meant by *class* here? $H_1(M)=\ker(\d_1)/\range(\d_2)$, where the chain complex is
$$\ldots \sr{\d_3}{\lra} C_2\sr{\d_2}{\lra}C_1\sr{\d_1}{\lra}C_0\lra 0.$$
How $L$ could be seen as a (formal linear combination of maps $\Delta^1\to M)\in\ker(\d_1)$?

2. I've seen that $H_0(M)=\Z^C=H_2(M)$, where $C$ is the set of connected components of $M$. $H_1(M)=\Z^S$, for some set $S$, since $M$ is oriented. Also $H_i(M)=0$ for all $i>2$.

Comment: When you say you don't know where to start, [I don't believe you](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933). You know what the involved concepts are, you know a little about how they interact. You might not know exactly how a finished proof begins, but that's an entirely different story. Please, tell us what you know.

Comment: @Arthur, edited.